# Add Image on another Image in iOS considering alpha parts

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, cifilter, ciimage

I have tried, compositing filters, both ATop and Over, But did not get the required Image as out put.
what I want is something like this:
[image]

NOTE: both the Image1 and Border are png Images.

Now what i am getting is either the border1 image or the image1 image, it seems they are not considering the alpha parts in border1 image, its removing the alpha channel and am left with a white background under the border image instead of image 1 peeking out.

Any idea about how to proceed? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the UIImage converted to CIImage with data as png, with this following code

```
 CIImage *paper1 =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPNGImage.png"])];
```

This Solves the problem, since earlier times the UIImage (though in .png format) was getting converted into a jpeg format CIImage.

Comment: i'm still getting one image from these two :( how can i solve it

Comment: http://innofied.com/add-stylish-frames-to-your-photos-in-iphone/

.this is my blog, i have solved the problem and updated in my blog